# ggplot2 histogram: show labels at start of each bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

It might be something obvious that I'm missing, but considering the histogram below

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
  geom_histogram(color="white") +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

I want labels (for example 1) to be at the start or end of a bar, not in midpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to customize the boundary of each bin with the `breaks` parameter in the `geom_histogram`. If you want to label at the start or end of bins, then you just need to make sure the `breaks` for label have a step that is a multiple of the bin width (or the step in the cut breaks):

```
cut_breaks = seq(0, 5, 0.2)
lab_breaks = seq(0, 5, 1)         # make sure 1 here is a multiple of 0.2

ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
    geom_histogram(color="white", breaks = cut_breaks) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = lab_breaks) +
    theme_light()
```

[image]

---

Here is a different set of *breaks*:

```
cut_breaks = seq(0, 5, 0.2)
lab_breaks = seq(0, 5, 0.6)                  # 0.6 is a multiple of 0.2

ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
    geom_histogram(color="white", breaks = cut_breaks) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = lab_breaks) +
    theme_light()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try `position_nudge` (and play with its input parameter to get the desired result):

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
  geom_histogram(color="white",position=position_nudge(x=0.25)) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you add a text line with the following placement instruction it will put them where you want them to be but you will need to fill in that `label =` part with the label you want it to print.

```
  ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, label =)) +
    geom_histogram(color="white") +
    theme_light()+
    geom_text(aes(y = y + 0.05), vjust = 0)
```